# Book series with a boy that could create portals from coloured shapes

Tags: story-identification, novel

The first book has a black werewolf-like creature on the front cover and I believe the third book was about a boy who could see coloured shapes and manipulate them into creating portals to other worlds/dimensions.

The last time I read them was when I was in school.

Comment: When were you in school? Were they paperbacks? Please visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to elicit further details to edit into your question.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I was in secondary school, I remember there were about 5 or 6 books in the series, I remember there being some sort of wizard in it aswell

Comment: But what *year* were you in school? You could be 36 years old or you might be 2,000 years old and we wouldn’t know.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots sending users to Valorum’s guide I think would be better; tag info is hard to read on mobile as there’s no responsive design for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The Demonata* by Darren Shan? Started in 2005, ten books total.

The cover of the first book (*Lord Loss*, 2005) has a werewolf:

[image: black werewolf on red background. Reads "it's in the blood"]

[TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheDemonata) has a character matching your recollection of a guy making portals out of coloured shapes only he can see:

> [Blessed with Suck](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlessedWithSuck): **Kernel has always been able to see patches of light floating around, and can use them to create inter-dimensional demon portals.** On one hand, it gave him his little brother, Art.. On the other hand...having anything to do with demons in this world will not end well for you. Particularly considering Art is Lord Loss's demonic maggot-infested pet baby. Plus, there's the whole "everyone thinks I'm insane" thing that he had to deal with.

---

Found with the Google query `scifi book create "portals * shapes"` which returned [the series' Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Demonata), which has the above cover as an illustration; the werewolf seemed promising, given the details you had provided.